# str object has no attribue 'convert'

Tags: python

```
#Feature extraction on single image
img = data_path[0][0]#PIL image
img_gray = img.convert('L') #Converting to grayscale
img_arr = np.array(img_gray) #Converting to array
plt.imshow(img_gray)
```

---

The error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d0363a4af103> in <module>
      1 # Feature extraction on single image
      2 img = data_path[0][0]#PIL image
----> 3 img_gray = img.convert('L') #Converting to grayscale
      4 img_arr = np.array(img_gray) #Converting to array`
      5 plt.imshow(img_gray)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'convert'
```

How can I solve this attribute issue?

Comment: `data_path[0][0]` is obviously returning a string and not an object that has a method "convert"

Comment: You have to read the image then after convert in to gray-scale `img = Image.open('image.png')` `img.convert('L')`

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Show `print(data_path)`

Answer (score 1):

as the @LainShelvington commented   `img = data_path[0][0]` statement is assign string value of given path to `img` variable so it `img.convert('L')` gives **AtrributeError**

below code may help you to soluve your issue:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as Image

img = Image.imread(data_path[0][0])     
img_gray=img.convert('L')    
img_arr = np.array(img_gray) 
plt.imshow(img_gray)
```

Comment: Most likely, you'll want to remove one or both of the indices.